# Codeigniter use Codeigniter models from outside script

Tags: php, codeigniter

There was a great post that applied to CI 1.7.2 about using CI models outside CI. It worked like a charm.

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Calling_CI_models_from_outside_script/

Then I upgraded to 2.0 and the code written in the above post was no longer applicable. I am having a hard time trying to get this to work in 2.0. The Config.php file is no longer in the libraries folder in addition to the Language.php and Model.php files.

Does anyone have an idea of how to port this to 2.0 ?

I only need the models. I was using them in an incoming email extension to our application and using the CI models that we had written saved a lot of time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what this package does, or what issues you're having (forgot to say?), but in 2.0 you need to be looking in the "core" directory rather than the "codeigniter" directory.